# Struggling to get a simple OnClickListener to work,

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    LinearLayout background;
    Button btnRed, btnBlue, btnGreen;
    Boolean Red, Blue;
    Boolean Green = true;
    TextView player1Count, player2Count;
    int count1, count2;





    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
        btnRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
        btnBlue =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
        btnGreen =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
        player1Count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1Count);
        player2Count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2Count);





        btnGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Green){
               count1 = Integer.parseInt(player1Count.getText().toString());
               count1++;
              player1Count.setText(count1);
            }
        }});

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? It should be fairly simple: every view is identified in the java code, then when the green button is clicked, if the boolean "green" is true (which I've set it to for testing), it gets the string from a textview (starts at "0"), converts it to an int, then adds one to it and changes the textview accordingly. However it crashes every time. Anyone have any idea why it's not working?

Comment: please add the Logcat

Comment: On what line does it crash, what is the error message?

Comment: At the moment I have 3 buttons and 2 text views, only the green button actually has code. The program starts up alright, but as soon as I click the green button, it says "Unfortunately, <app_name> has crashed." I looked in the debug log thing and I can't find any meaningful error message, only fatal exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
  player1Count.setText(count1);
```

do:

```
  player1Count.setText(String.valueOf(count1));
```

The problem is that if you pass an integer to the setText() it will understand as a 'String resource ID)..not as the value of the variable.

It is basically 'thinking' that you wanna use this method:    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

instead of this:
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I've been trying to get this working for a while now. Recently started learning android studio (i.e. java and xml) after failing to grasp Xcode. Thanks again for your help!